# Jquery - parse XML received from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, url

I have this URL, that I supposedly should receive an XML from. So far I have this:

```
    function GetLocationList(searchString)
    {

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://konkurrence.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=" + searchString,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

    //Use received data here.
    alert("test");

    }
});
```

Tried to debug with firebug, but it doesn't go into the success method. 
Though, in DreamWeaver it **is** able to post a simple alert, which is inside the success method.
I tried writing **xml** as dataType, but it doesn't work (in DreamWeaver) when I write alert(data). 
But it shows an alert with the entire XML, when I write **html** as dataType.

How do I get the XML correctly, and how do I parse and for example get the "StopLocation" element?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add an Error function as well.

See [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This will give you all the informations you need to debug your code with Firefox.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://konkurrence.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=" + searchString,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

    //Use received data here.
    alert("test");

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
      // debug here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse it first, and then you can search for the attributes. like this.

```
success: function(data) {
        var xml = $.parseXML(data)
        $(xml).find('StopLocation').each(function()
    {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        alert(name);
    }       
    );
```

this will give you the name of each StopLocation.

hope this helps, you can use the same method for all other attributes in the document also.

Comment: This seems to work in DreamWeaver. I get the attributes in an alert. But still doesn't work in neither Firefox or Chrome.