# Passing PHP value to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm generating XML data within a PHP file:-

```
    private static function getAddressesAsXML($addressArr) {

    $addressXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<addresslist></addresslist>");
    $addressXML->addAttribute("resultcount",(int)self::get_resultcount());

    $addressIndex = 0;

    foreach ($addressArr as $addressObject) {

        $addressNode = $addressXML->addChild("address");
        $addressNode->addAttribute("id",(int)$addressIndex);

        $addressNode->addChild("pickup",htmlspecialchars($addressObject->get_pickup()));
        $addressNode->addChild("dropoff",htmlspecialchars($addressObject->get_dropoff()));
        $addressNode->addChild("BookingDateTime",$addressObject->get_bookingtime());
        $addressNode->addChild("Car",$addressObject->get_car());
        $addressNode->addChild("JbMessage",$addressObject->get_status());
        $addressNode->addChild("Zone",$addressObject->get_zone());
        $addressNode->addChild("CustomerFare",$addressObject->get_fare());
        $addressNode->addChild("PassName",$addressObject->get_passenger());
        $addressNode->addChild("CarType",$addressObject->get_cartype());
        $addressNode->addChild("Tel",$addressObject->get_tel());
        $addressNode->addChild("Comments",$addressObject->get_comments());

        $addressIndex += 1;

    }

echo $addressXML->asXML();

}
```

which outputs:-

```
<addresslist resultcount="2">
    <address id="0">
        <pickup>ADDRESS 1</pickup>
        <dropoff>ADDRESS 2</dropoff>
        <bookingdatetime>16/04/2014 12:03:57</bookingdatetime>
        <car></car>
        <jbmessage></jbmessage>
        <zone>NO ZONE</zone>
        <customerfare>3.5</customerfare>
        <passname>TEST</passname>
        <cartype>CAR</cartype>
        <tel>12345678912</tel>
        <comments></comments>
    </address>
</addresslist>
```

What I need to do is pass this to a jQuery file so I can display the information in a jQGrid. How would it be possible to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079875/jquery-parse-xml-received-from-url

Comment: Can you output it as JSON? If so, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XML use JSON. It's natively supporten in JavaScript, is smaller and faster.
To encode array/stdClass in PHP to JSON you can use json_encode